# Overriding properties which conform to protocols

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, llvm

I seem to be getting a new error when using LLVM Compiler 2.0, which I haven't had before.

I have a protocol called [DTGridViewDelegate](https://github.com/danielctull/DTGridView/blob/master/DTGridView.h#L188) defined as:

`@protocol DTGridViewDelegate <UIScrollViewDelegate>`

I have a property called [`delegate` on DTGridView](https://github.com/danielctull/DTGridView/blob/master/DTGridView.h#L116) (a subclass of UIScrollView, which itself has a `delegate` property). This is defined as:

`@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet id<DTGridViewDelegate> delegate;`

Now the message I get is:

`DTGridView.h:116:63: error: property type 'id<DTGridViewDelegate>' is incompatible with type 'id<UIScrollViewDelegate>' inherited from 'UIScrollView'`

Because I had said that the DTGridViewDelegate conforms to UIScrollViewDelegate, I thought that this would be ok to override this property in this way, and indeed this is the first compiler to suggest there is a problem.

I have fixed the error by declaring the property as such:

`@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet id<DTGridViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate> delegate;`

I am wondering whether this is a compiler issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your setup looks like the same one used in the case of UITableView inheriting from UIScrollView. The UITableViewDelegate protocol inherits from UIScrollViewDelegate protocol.

I set up the following which compiles fine:

```
// .h
@protocol ParentClassDelegate
-(NSString *) aDelegateMethod;
@end

@interface ParentClass : NSObject {
    id delegate;
}
@property(nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet id <ParentClassDelegate> delegate;
@end

//.m
@implementation ParentClass
@synthesize delegate;

-(id) delegate{
    return @"Parent delegate";
}//-------------------------------------(id) delegate------------------------------------

-(void) setDelegate:(id)someObj{
    delegate=someObj;
}//-------------------------------------(id) setDelegate------------------------------------
@end

//.h
@protocol ChildClassDelegate <ParentClassDelegate>
-(NSArray *) anotherDelegateMethod;
@end

@interface ChildClass : ParentClass{
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet id <ChildClassDelegate> delegate;
@end

//.m
@implementation ChildClass
//@synthesize delegate;

-(id) delegate{
    return @"childDelegate";
}//-------------------------------------(id) delegate------------------------------------

-(void) setDelegate:(id)someObj{
    delegate=someObj;
}//-------------------------------------(id) setDelegate------------------------------------

@end
```

Not sure what is causing your problem. I would note that in the header the UITableViewDelegate protocol looks like:

```
@protocol UITableViewDelegate<NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

... so maybe the compiler likes things more explicit sometimes.

I would suggest a clean and build. That solves a lot of problems.

Comment: I turned on stricter warnings from http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2009-11-07/warnings using Wolf's script here: http://rentzsch.tumblr.com/post/237349423/hoseyifyxcodewarnings-scpt. Which probably explains why you're not seeing the warning/error.

Comment: You're totally right though, I forgot about UITableViewDelegate, which I based that code off in the first place! It seems to me like the first way shouldn't be throwing up a warning for it. Also, I find it odd that UITableViewDelegate says it conforms to NSObject when it also conforms to UIScrollViewDelegate, which itself conforms to NSObject.

Comment: So after some further discussion with @MikeAbdullah, it turns out I needed to put the protocol declarations before the class interface. The @protocol DTGridViewDelegate wasn't saying that it conformed to <UIScrollViewDelegate> by the time the compiler reached my property declaration.

Comment: I finally cracked and started to try to fix this, and lo and behold the problem was solved yesterday! Daniel - looking forward to the fix showing up in your repository :)

Answer (score 5):

Since there isn't a formal Objective-C language specification, it's impossible to say whether the compiler is behaving properly. All we can say is that Apple's gcc doesn't seem to have a problem with the above scenario, though it's conceptually unsound as it can break [Liskov substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), since `delegate` is [covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29) from `UIScrollView` to `DTGridView` (though covariance is just as much a problem). What would happen if you passed a `DTGridView` to code expecting a `UIScrollView`, which then proceeded to set `delegate` to an object that conformed to `UIScrollViewDelegate` but not `DTGridViewDelegate`?

Comment: That is perfectly true. What I find odd is that in both ways I've declared the delegate, this would break as you describe, yet the compiler only warns against one of them.